# PostgreSQL 10: pg_ctl status not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

I want to be able to use pg_ctl to manage my crewdb database.
However, when I use pg_ctl status I get the following error:

```
chh1@chh1:~$ pg_ctl status
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
```

I am not sure why this is the case nor how to fix it because when I do:

```
chh1@chh1:~$ which pg_ctl
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl

chh1@chh1:~$ which initdb
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/initdb

chh1@chh1:~$ whoami
chh1

crewdb=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 chh1      | Superuser                                                  | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}


chh1@chh1:~$ cat .profile
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/10/main
PGDATABASE=crewdb
PGUSER=postgres

export PATH PGDATA PGDATABASE PGUSER
```

I did try PGUSER=chh1 instead of PGUSER=postgres in .profile but still get the same error message when I issue the command pg_ctl status.
Anyone able to help me out on this? I have the following postgresql cluster:

```
chh1@chh1:~$ ps -ef | grep postgres
postgres  2094     1  0 11:08 ?        00:00:01 /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
postgres  2114  2094  0 11:08 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: logger process
postgres  2123  2094  0 11:08 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: checkpointer process
postgres  2124  2094  0 11:08 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: writer process
postgres  2125  2094  0 11:08 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: wal writer process
postgres  2126  2094  0 11:08 ?        00:00:01 postgres: 10/main: autovacuum launcher process
postgres  2127  2094  0 11:08 ?        00:00:01 postgres: 10/main: stats collector process
postgres  2128  2094  0 11:08 ?        00:00:00 postgres: 10/main: bgworker: logical replication launcher
chh1      6401 17468  0 17:47 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

It also seems unusual that I have to be root to open the data directory such as in:

```
chh1@chh1:~$ cd /var/lib/postgresql/10/main
bash: cd: /var/lib/postgresql/10/main: Permission denied

root@chh1:/var/lib/postgresql/10/main# ls -l
total 100
drwx------ 20 postgres postgres 4096 Jan 13 11:08 ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 24 19:12 ../
drwx------  6 postgres postgres 4096 Aug 10 23:04 base/
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres   44 Jan 13 11:08 current_logfiles
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan 13 11:08 global/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan 13 11:08 log/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 24 19:12 pg_commit_ts/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 24 19:12 pg_dynshmem/
drwx------  4 postgres postgres 4096 Jan 13 11:13 pg_logical/
drwx------  4 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 24 19:12 pg_multixact/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan 13 11:08 pg_notify/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 24 19:12 pg_replslot/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 24 19:12 pg_serial/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 24 19:12 pg_snapshots/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan 13 11:08 pg_stat/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 24 19:12 pg_stat_tmp/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  3 06:12 pg_subtrans/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 24 19:12 pg_tblspc/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 24 19:12 pg_twophase/
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres    3 Jul 24 19:12 PG_VERSION
drwx------  3 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  3 06:12 pg_wal/
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jul 24 19:12 pg_xact/
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres   88 Jul 24 19:12 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  130 Jan 13 11:08 postmaster.opts
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  108 Jan 13 11:08 postmaster.pid
```

My thinking is to change the file permissions in `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/` to chh1:chh1 but am not sure if it is safe to do so without putting my data at risk.
please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: The database is running as user `postgres` and you need to use the same user account for `pg_ctl`.

Comment: I tried ```su - postgres
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
``` to then run pg_ctl status. That did not work.

Comment: Try `sudo -u postgres -i` to switch to the `postgres` user. If you're `root`, you can use `su - postgres`.

Comment: I tried what you said but get the following:
`chh1@chh1:~$ sudo -u postgres -i
postgres@chh1:~$ pg_ctl status
pg_ctl: command not found`

Comment: It seems `pg_ctl` is not in your `PATH`, so either add `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin` to your `PATH` if you want to use `pg_ctl` or use `pg_ctlcluster` instead like `pg_ctlcluster 10 main status`. You can list available clusters and their statuses with `pg_lsclusters`.

Comment: I'd guess **postgres** wasn't started with `pg_ctlcluster 10 main` or `systemctl start postgres.service`, hence the unusual (inaccessible to anyone but user `postgres`) directory for the PID file and maybe the UNIX sockets too. Usually `external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid` in the appropriate `postgresql.conf` file.

Comment: My path is, chh1@chh1:~$ echo $PATH
/home/chh1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin

Comment: I tried `pg_ctlcluster 10 main status` after `sudo -u postgres -i` and got 
postgres@chh1:~$ pg_ctlcluster 10 main status
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 2122)
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres "-D" "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main" "-c" "config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf" But why does pg_ctl not work to manage the database.

Comment: Piotr P. Karwasz: I have external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid uncommented in '/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf'. However when I run:
sudo find \ -name '10-main.pid' I get the location /run/postgresql/10-main.pid. Not sure what this means thow.

Comment: `pg_ctl` needs some environment variables and options (e.g., where is the config file) to function properly. `pg_ctlcluster 10 main <command>` calls `pg_ctl <command>` in the correct way.